# relative href path goes wrong in angularjs with html5mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm using AngularJS to handle my urls with html5mode turned on. I'm also using the gulp-angular generator to build the project.

**Situation:**

index.js

```
   $locationProvider
        .html5Mode(true);
```

index.html

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp,src}) styles/app.css -->
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/index.css">
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<base href="/" />
```

**Problem**

When url is `example.com/somepage`, index.css is gotten from `example.com/app/index.css` but when url is `example.com/somepage/somedeeperpage`, and I refresh the page, index.css is gotten from `example.com/somepage/app/index.css`

I want to be able to use the relative paths as by default in the angular-gulp generator.

Do I have to change to base tag, or index.css rel path in the gulpfile?

Strangely, the relative path is working fine for finding index.js

Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** just figured out that if I put the  tag **before** the injection of styles it works... My index.html looks like this now:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
```

Previous answer :

Had the same issue, made this work by adding  in my index.html file and by changing the gulp-inject config in gulp/inject.js :

Before :

```
var injectOptions = {
  ignorePath: [options.src, options.tmp + '/serve'],
  addRootSlash: false
};
```

After :

```
var injectOptions = {
  ignorePath: [options.src, options.tmp + '/serve']
};
```

Comment: just got this issue and first post solve my issue. Thanks man.

Comment: I never would have tried moving the base tag up in the head! Thanks for posting the solution